# Make some code "live" in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to make a click event like this live

```
$('.link').live('click',function(){
```

But i dont know how to make this live

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    $(".mydiv[id="+hash+"]").css("background-color","#eefde1");
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: what is the point on making it as live? I dont see any event binding in the second code snippet

Comment: You mean run every time the page hash changes, i.e. you need to hook into the history APIs?

Comment: Just for the record: `.live()` is depricated since version 1.9. You should stick to updated code and use `.on()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to listen for the hash to change.

As far as I know, jQuery doesn't support this out-of-the-box, but you could use this plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ or use the native javascript function `window.onhashchange` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).hashChange(function() { ... });
```

see: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: That's nearly four years old. Is that still the case - jQuery still doesn't provide it?

Comment: @Rup: it is too specific to be built-in.